# LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am getting the above error, the error message complains about a 0-dimensional array

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------------  --------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call  last)
<ipython-input-110-2e59b52b853b> in <module>()
  8 
  9 # compute det and C_N
---> 10 const = np.sqrt(np.linalg.det((dof-2)/dof)*C_N)
 11 print(const)

<__array_function__ internals> in det(*args, **kwargs)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in  det(a)
2110     """
2111     a = asarray(a)
-> 2112     _assert_stacked_2d(a)
2113     _assert_stacked_square(a)
2114     t, result_t = _commonType(a)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _assert_stacked_2d(*arrays)
205         if a.ndim < 2:
206             raise LinAlgError('%d-dimensional array given. Array  must be '
--> 207                     'at least two-dimensional' % a.ndim)
208 
209 def _assert_stacked_square(*arrays):

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
npts = 5000
dof  = 3
X_r = np.arange(npts)
product = X_r * X_r.transpose()  
Rowsum = [np.sum(product[i]) for i in range(npts)]
C_N = np.sum(Rowsum)/(npts - 1)

 # compute det and C_N 
const = np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(((dof-2)/dof)*C_N))
print(const)
```

Many thanks to the intrepid who care and dare to read through all this.

Comment: `(dof-2)/dof` is a scalar. It does not have a determinant.

Comment: And `C_N` seems to be a scalar as well...

Comment: Ok, thank you so much I realized that two of them are scalar